# console.dir() Equivalent Using jQuery Mobile with phonegap in xCode

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, xcode4.2

Need to be able to debug properly and see stuff in the console. Console.dir() doesn't work in xcode when I'm running ios simulations. Whats the best way to write something to the console in a html file? Can I use NSLog()? I don't know much objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough...it was console.log() not console.dir...all better :)